# redux-persist autoRehydrate not defined in new version

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-persist

I'm newby to Redux. I was trying to persist data on local storage through `redux-persist`. I followed the tutorial and the data stored in storage as below.

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware, compose} from 'redux';
 import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';
 import {persistStore, autoRehydrate} from 'redux-persist';
 import reducer from '../reducer';

 var defaultState = {
     todos: []
 };



 exports.configureStore = (initialState=defaultState) => {

     var store = createStore(reducer, initialState, compose(
         autoRehydrate()
     ));
     persistStore(store, {storage: AsyncStorage});
     return store;
 }
```

And here is my `App.js`.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import Main from './app/components/Main';
import {configureStore} from './app/store';

export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
     <Provider store={configureStore()}>
        <Main/>
     </Provider>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});
```

But I guess, there is new update in `redux-persist`. So, with this code I get the error like below.

[image]

As I understand, within new update there is no more `autoRehydrate`. But I can't handle, how to update the code so it works with new version. Can you help me, please?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48514147/rnredux-persist-autorehydrate-is-not-a-function